# Add content of one page to another

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Can i add the content part of this link into my webpage

```
http://rid3201.org/site/club_members2.php?id=MTk3Ng==
```

I want to avoid the header part.Can i use iframe or object for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

With it you can get the whole page and select only the html element you need (I assume it would be table).

Then you can pass it to your page.

Comment: it's a server side code. There is plenty documentation and examples online about it. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the domain *rid3201.org*, you can do it with jQuery:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

**heads up**!
If are not the owner of the domain, you CAN'T do it via jQuery.

The documentation of [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) says:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

An alternative to jQuery is using [XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), coding with a backend language, like .Net

After you catch the url source, you have to clean the code to get only the div you want.